# How do I turn off mouse block selection in IntelliJ?

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea

For some reason, dragging the mouse cursor started doing block selects instead of the normal line select mode:

[image]

(Please ignore the fact that this image is from Visual Studio and not IntelliJ)

I tried pressing scroll-lock, pressing and releasing the alt/ctrl/shift keys, but still selecting doesn't revert to the normal "select full lines" mode. When I click and hold, then drag the mouse, I get a block (rectangle) selection.

Do you know how to undo this?

P.S. I'm running IntelliJ 9 on Ubuntu.

P.S. Holding SHIFT and pressing the up arrow button also does block select instead of normal multiline select.

Comment: That IntelliJ feature gave me cancer.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd> to switch between *Column* and *Insert* selection mode.

---

Copying comment from *brent.payne* below:

> If you are on ubuntu running on a bootcamp mac (macbook pro here) then the key stroke is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>. <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> = <kbd>Ins</kbd> since no <kbd>Ins</kbd> key exists on the macbook pro

Comment: If you are on ubuntu running on a bootcamp mac (macbook pro here) then the key stroke is Alt+Shift+Fn+Enter .  Fn+Enter = Ins since no Ins key exists on the macbook pro. Edit: seems inline html for keyboard keys doesn't work in comments <kbd>Fail</kbd>

Comment: maybe I needed lower case <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, nope guess not

Answer (score 235):

"Edit" > "Column Selection Mode"

Comment: Much easier to find than messing with key combos on Mac vs Linux vs Windows.

Comment: Key combo didn't work for me, this was very clear and quick.

Comment: @sscarduzio I didn't know what it's called so I ended up deleting my entire Android Studio configuration to fix it and "reset it to normal" -_- this solution is less intrusive

Comment: is there a way to set this in preferences? I could not find it and it is super special annoying!

Comment: Use this answer and fix the problem once. Use Pylinux's answer and you can fix it forever: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38346300/1339923 @pferrel It may save your sanity, too.

Answer (score 22):

First you do

```
"Edit" > "Column Selection Mode"
```

THEN you go into

```
Settings -> Keymap
```

and search for `Column Selection Mode`, then you right click it and *remove* the key bindings so that it doesn't come on again.

Comment: This is what I was after, and I'm so thankful to you! :)

Answer (score 21):

CMD + SHIFT + *

On a Macbook pro with UK keyboard

Answer (score 19):

Or if you are on MacOS: simply press <kbd>⇧⌘A</kbd> in Editor, search for **Column Section Mode** and just turn it **OFF**.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me
On Windows/Linux: Press Alt + Shift + Insert.
On macOS: Press Cmd + Shift + 8.